# Quotes in heredocs in Emacs perl mode

Tags: perl, emacs

I am using `perl-mode` in Emacs, but there seems to be a problem with syntax highlighting when there are unmatched quotes inside a heredoc string. Consider the following perl code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use v5.14;

my $str= <<END;
Hello'
END

my $b=3;

print $str;
```

This gives the following screenshot:

[image]

So all syntax highlighting after the heredoc string is lost. I am using Gnu Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, the Stack Overflow syntax highlighter appears to suffer from the same problem.

I haven't coded in Perl in a few years, but I remember strongly preferring `cperl-mode` over `perl-mode` when I did. I've just copied this snippet into a `cperl-mode` buffer and it seems to highlight correctly.

If you're open to trying this out a simple `M-x cperl-mode` should work for one buffer. To use `cperl-mode` for all Perl buffers, something like this

```lisp
(fset 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)
```

should cause `cperl-mode` to be used wherever `perl-mode` would normally be used. (Note that `cperl-mode` comes with Emacs.)

Answer (score 4):

Currently, perl-mode does not handle the `<<END` syntax for heredocs, only the `<<"END"`, `<<'END'`, or `<<\END`' syntax.

I just fixed it in the Emacs "trunk".